# how can I active update or insert row in datagridview1 after this commands

Tags: c#

```
 //insert one record with this code
sqlcon.Open();
string query1 = "Sp_InsertUpdateStudent";
SqlCommand cmnd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, sqlcon);
cmnd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmnd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtid.Text.ToString());
cmnd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentcode", txtcode.Text.ToString());
cmnd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtfirstname.Text.ToString());
cmnd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtlastname.Text.ToString());
cmnd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(" complete ");}
```

//in this place how can I Select insert Row in datagridview1

Answer (score 0):

First you need add the columns to the dataGridView like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Id", "Id");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("studentcode", "studentcode");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("firstname", "firstname");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("lastname", "lastname");
```

Then you can pass the data to your dataGridView

```
object[] rowData = new object[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];

rowData[0] = txtid.Text;     
rowData[1] = txtcode.Text;        
rowData[2] = txtfirstname.Text;        
rowData[3] = txtlastname.Text;     
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData);
```